# System identification toolbox vs. Econometrics toolbox in time series analysis

Tags: time-series, matlab

I'm doing time series analysis and I want to build an ARIMAX-model for my data. I was just curious if someone could give me any recommendations on whether to use System Ide. or Econometrics toolbox in Matlab? Which one would you prefer for general time series analysis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jjepsuomi,

You get what you pay for.  What you are trying to do is really complicated.  I would suggest not trying to reinvent the wheel, but buying software that can handle the complexities of denominator structure on your causals plus outliers like pulses, level shifts, changes in trend and seasonality.  I would recommend looking at SAS, Autobox, SPSS.  We developed Autobox.

Comment: +1 Thank you for your reply. Nevertheless, If I had to use time series functions of SI-toolbox or Eco.-toolbox, which one would you choose? =)

Comment: I would suggest you go here. http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/  It looks like an active board and you will get a better opinion. Don't forget to ask about the things I warned you about!!

Answer (score 0):

As of MATLAB 2013b, you cannot compile ARMAX() of the System Identification Toolbox into a standalone application. As this was no-go for us we moved to arima() of the Econometrics Toolbox.